# Is there a way to watch a change of the i18n's current locale?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, internationalization, vue-i18n

How can I call a function when the language/locale changes while using i18n?
Should I use Vuex or does [vue-i18n](https://kazupon.github.io/vue-i18n/) has a method that allows me to do that?

Comment: Please include more information about you are trying to do, e.g. what command are you trying to run with the vue cli?

Answer (score 17):

You could watch `$i18n.locale` for any changes but usually, **you** do change this kind of thing. What is your use-case for such need ?

```js
watch: {
  '$i18n.locale': function(newVal, oldVal) {
    console.log('locale change', newVal)
  }
}
```

Comment: This does not work. Nothing is triggered by changes on `i18n.locale`. To be clear, my i18n mechanism is working fine, only this watch is not. I tried the rule with and without the leading dollar sign. I'm on vue 2.6.12, vue-i18n 8.22.4 and vuex 3.6.2. I'm not downvoting this because versions could be the issue, but for the 13 of you that upvoted this, I would like to know how did this work.

Comment: @Ricardo not sure why this is not working for you, it all depends on how you implemented it I suppose. Usual way is to work with `$i18n` hence why the watcher should work. Still, if it's not feel free to ask a new question with a [repro] or at least all the relevant details regarding your configuration.

Answer (score 5):

Not sure about your setup, but with Vue3 in [SFC](https://vuejs.org/guide/scaling-up/sfc.html) I am using it as follows:

#### New Way:

(changed according to @kissu's tip)

```html
<script setup lang="ts">
import { useI18n } from 'vue-i18n';

const { t, locale } = useI18n();

watch(locale, () => {
  console.log('locale', locale.value);
});
</script>
```

It fires every time the locale changes (for example with a language toggle outside of the actual file/component).

---

#### Old Way:

```html
<script setup lang="ts">
import i18n from '@/i18n';

const locale = ref(i18n.global.locale);

watch(locale, () => {
  console.log('locale', locale.value);
});
</script>
```

Comment: If you want a try Composition API-y way of doing this, I recommend using `useI18n` and `t` even: https://vue-i18n.intlify.dev/guide/advanced/composition.html

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me (based on the "old way" @goldensoju mentioned):

```
const currentLocale = computed(() => i18n.global.locale)

watch(currentLocale, (value) => {
  console.log(`locale change: ${value}`)
})
```