# How to watch for i18n locale change in Nuxt?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, nuxtjs3, vue-i18n, nuxt-i18n

I've installed **nuxt 3** and **i18n**

I want to **change** document direction when **locale** switched

for example `<body dir="ltr">` to `<body dir="rtl" >`

But I couldn't find any **callback** function for that in the document !

i know I can put some watch on $i18n.locale But I think it's not **best** way to do that .

I remember in Nuxt 2 / i18n we had a callback named "**onLocaleChanged**" but I couldn't find that in new **version** !

`plugins/i18n.ts`

```js
import { createI18n } from 'vue-i18n'
import en from '~~/locales/en'
import fa from '~~/locales/fa'
export default defineNuxtPlugin(({ vueApp }) => {
  const i18n = createI18n({
    legacy: false,
    globalInjection: true,
    locale: 'fa',
    messages: {
      en,fa
    }
  })
  vueApp.use(i18n)
})
```

`package.json`

```json
{
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "build": "nuxt build",
    "dev": "nuxt dev",
    "generate": "nuxt generate",
    "preview": "nuxt preview",
    "postinstall": "nuxt prepare"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@intlify/unplugin-vue-i18n": "^0.7.0",
    "@intlify/vite-plugin-vue-i18n": "^6.0.3",
    "@nuxtjs/tailwindcss": "^5.3.3",
    "nuxt": "3.0.0-rc.10",
    "sass": "^1.55.0",
    "sass-loader": "10.1.1",
    "tailwindcss-flip": "^1.0.0",
    "vue-i18n": "^9.2.2"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@heroicons/vue": "^2.0.11",
    "@kyvg/vue3-notification": "^2.4.1",
    "@nuxt-hero-icons/outline": "^1.0.1",
    "@nuxt-hero-icons/solid": "^1.0.1",
    "@pinia/nuxt": "^0.4.2",
    "@vueform/multiselect": "^2.5.2",
    "axios": "^0.27.2",
    "daisyui": "^2.28.0",
    "jenesius-vue-modal": "^1.7.2",
    "sweetalert2": "^11.4.33",
    "vee-validate": "^4.6.7",
    "vue-recaptcha-v3": "^2.0.1",
    "vue3-loading-overlay": "^0.0.0",
    "yup": "^0.32.11"
  }
}
```

Comment: Try to check the Vue devtools and inspect the `$i18n` instance there, you will probably see something that you can `watch` then, like the `locale`. There is no specific event emitted but this [kind of solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67141437/8816585) should still work if adapted towards Composition API.

Comment: thnx I couln't find i18n instance methods , and I did like that solution in the linke

Comment: Hi , I couldn't find any callback for that

Comment: Can't you do what you want to inside of the block of the watcher?

Comment: As I said in question I can do that with watch But I think it's not best solution !

Comment: It's a totally viable and working one, no issue with it. Will produce the exact same result at the end (no performance issues or alike).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use something like [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67141437/8816585).

```js
watch: {
  '$i18n.locale': function(newVal, oldVal) {
    console.log('locale change', newVal)
  }
}
```

Since I'm not sure that there is a given event for this purpose.